# Relationship between norms and measures

Tags: measure-theory, normed-spaces

A norm is defined on a vector space, a measure on a $\sigma$-algebra. However, they share many properties.

$\mu(U) \geq 0$ and $\|\cdot\| \geq 0$
$\mu(\emptyset) = 0$ and $\|0\| = 0$
$\mu(U+V) \leq \mu(U)+\mu(V)$ and $\|x+y\| \leq \|x\|+\|y\|$

The only one missing is a connection to $\|ax\| = |a|\|x\|$, as there's no multiplication of sets. Measures seem to be more primitive in that sense. Are there any useful way to compare these notions?

Comment: "Two" is not "many". The function $\sqrt{x}$ on $[0,\infty)$ also shares those properties, as do other functions. This does not indicate a deep connection of $\sqrt{\cdot}$ with measures.

Comment: @CrazyIvan I realized they share a third property as well. Three out of four seems to be relatively many.

Comment: The properties you list show they are both examples of metrics: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space). For $\mu$, you would have to identify measurable sets that differ by a measure zero set, however.

Comment: @user363464 I realized that, but that's a binary relation, so there's that too.